Clipping in Eevee Rendered View
I've found this issue just today. When I enter rendered view with Eevee, my viewport just starts doing this. In material view I get this weird green...volume? around my scene This also happens to some degree in cycles,but it's just my background that gets clipped.
Update!: For some reason, this is all caused by the plane I used as a backdrop, as soon as I delete it, the problem goes away, but I still need a solution for that! I need to have a backdrop




i am not sure but this might be a graphics card problem. Did you update your graphic card driver?

Hey Chris! For some reason this ended up being the plane I made. I deleted it, restarted blender, made another one and it worked for some reason. I do have to update my drivers, but more than that I gotta upgrade from my GTX 970
